# Django/React set-cookie: csrftoken and X-CSRF-Token do not match and persists

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, csrf

I've been working through the nightmare that is decoupled React/Django and can't seem to figure out why my CSRF tokens, 1) do not match in the response, and 2) why the cookie is persisting between refreshes.

Django View:

```
def get_csrf_token(request):
    response = JsonResponse({'detail': 'CSRF cookie set'})
    response['X-CSRFToken'] = get_token(request)
    return response
```

Django CSRF Settings:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = None
```

React CSRF API Call:

```
  getCSRF = () => {
    fetch("/api/csrf/", {
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
      }
    })
        .then((res) => {
          let reqCsrfToken = res.headers.get("X-CSRFToken");
          this.setState({csrf: reqCsrfToken});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
```

Now, the problem is that every time I ping the view with this call, the response headers between the set-cookie and the x-csrftoken will be totally different.  Additionally, the original cookie value will persist across new calls and refreshes.

```
set-cookie: csrftoken=KceWlQsdiQuM.......
```

vs the `X-CSRFToken Value`

```
x-csrftoken: Ymx3NCe5dwh.......
```

I've checked and printed and logged everywhere, and the cookie value is always different.

Comment: If you're using react and django on 2 different domains (e.g. the frontend is not served by django itself), you should use token based authentication, and that will solve your problem of csrf. For your question, how are you storing your csrf token on client side, only in component state ?

Comment: Yes, storing the X-CSRF-Token in state. (I do need to update to hooks though.) The recommendation from DRF is to use sessions.